# Конвертировать массив json с объектами на кириллице в строку javascript

Tags: javascript, массивы, json, json-encode

У меня есть json массив по типу:

```
Вложение объекта: {Поле1: "", Поле файла: "name", Поле3: ""}
```

Как возможно его распарсить и вынести только значение: "Поле файла", если массив с кириллицей?
Пробовал преобразовать массив в строку через `JSON.stringify`, но непонятно как вынести значение Поле файла

Answer (score 2):

Что-то такое?

```js
let ar = [{Вложение: {Поле1: "", Поле2: "name", Поле3: ""}}];

console.log(ar)
console.log(ar[0])
console.log(ar[0].Вложение.Поле2)
```

либо у Вас  строка

```js
let ar = JSON.parse('[{"Вложение": {"Поле1": "", "Поле2": "name", "Поле3": ""}}]');

console.log(ar)
console.log(ar[0])
console.log(ar[0].Вложение.Поле2)
```

Comment: Немного не так указал массив, да, это строка, но выглядит вот так:  Вложение объекта: {Поле1: "", Поле файла: "name", Поле3: ""}

Comment: @DmitriyAndreevich если ответ помог то можно пометить как полезный